# How to initialize static class objects in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Lane.h**

```
class Lane{
    //other declarations..
public:
    Lane(){}
    static Lane left_line;
    static Lane right_line;
};
```

**Lane.cpp**

```
Lane Lane::left_line;
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(){
    Lane::left_line();  //doesn't work
```

What am I doing wrong or am I doing everything wrong. I am actually confused about how the static objects work exactly.

Comment: Show us the error messages.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type"

Comment: @Mat I am trying to initialize the left_line object through constructor.

Comment: That translates to "you are calling an object, which doesn't behave like a function, as a function anyway." To fix, get rid of the extra parentheses in your main function and access it as you would any other C++ object.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Thank you I get it now. But apparently the object gets initialized in the Lane.cpp. Is it possible to initialize it in main.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to do that, the goal of a static object is to be initialized once and used everywhere without thinking about it again. Maybe there's different behavior you're actually interested in seeing?

Comment: There are ways to do something which would work like you are describing, but what you should do is highly dependend on what and why you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez I am extracting lane lines from roads for car automation. I want to initialize the static left_line and right_line when they are detected on the first video frame.

Comment: @user3673025 Alright, so I suggest either rewording your question to include this information, or to start a new one since the correct solution has already been given. Also, FYI, we call these types of problems an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"; keep them in mind in the future to get quicker help!

Comment: @BrianRodriguez But I asked for how to initialize static class object. But yeah I would post another question asking about the good approach to my problem. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` members get declared inside a class and initialized once outside the class. There is no need to call the constructor once again. I've added a method to your `Lane` class to make it clearer.

```
class Lane{
    //other declarations..
public:
    Lane(){}
    static Lane left_line; //<declaration
    static Lane right_line;

   void use() {};
};
```

**Lane.cpp**

```
Lane Lane::left_line; //< initialisation, calls the default constructor of Lane
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
  // Lane::left_line(); //< would try to call a static function called left_line which does not exist
  Lane::left_line.use(); //< just use it, it was already initialised
}
```

You can make the initialisation even more obvious by doing this:

```
Lane Lane::left_line = Lane();
```

in Lane.cpp.

Comment: No. Static initialisation takes place before main gets called.